# How to send/accept JSON using JerseyTest Framework

Tags: json, jersey, testng, jersey-client, jersey-test-framework

I am attempting to write a simple test class that emulates a RESTful Web Service creating a Customer via  a `POST` method. The following fails at `assertEquals`, I receive a `400 Bad Request` response. I cannot use debugger to observe stack trace. However the console tells me the following...

INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:9998] 
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.

```
public class SimpleTest extends JerseyTestNg.ContainerPerMethodTest {

    public class Customer {
        public Customer() {}

        public Customer(String name, int id) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;

        @JsonProperty("id")
        private int id;
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(MyService.class);
    }

    @Path("hello")
    public static class MyService {
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public final Response createCustomer(Customer customer) {
            System.out.println("Customer data: " + customer.toString());
            return Response.ok("customer created").build();
        }
    }

    @Test
    private void test() {
        String json =   "{" +
                "\"name\": \"bill\", " +
                "\"id\": 4" +
                "}";
        final Response response = target("hello").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.json(json));
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of printing `response.toString()`, you can read the actual body using `response.readEntity(String.class)`. What you will find in the body is an error message from Jackson

> No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class simple.SimpleTest$Customer]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

At first glance your `Customer` class looks ok; it has a default constructor. But the really problem is that Jackson cannot instantiate it because it is a non-static inner class. So to fix it, simply make the `Customer` class `static`.

```
public static class Customer {}
```

As a general rule, when working with JSON and Jackson with Jersey, often when you get a 400, it a a problem with Jackson, and Jackson is pretty good at spitting out a meaningful message that will help us debug.

Comment: You are an amazing man. You have just solved a problem that had been stumping me for over 6 hours. THANK YOU

Comment: @JasonJavier Thank you for the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by the way. This is how I try to encourage Jersey related questions be asked. Something we can copy and paste into a single class to test. Even if the question is not related to the test framework, putting all the functionality into one runnable test helps to figure out the problem faster. It also helps the OP narrow down the problem area so the debugging is more focused.